# Spring Mongo Template not saving the list of custom objects to MongoDb

Tags: spring, mongodb, mongotemplate

I am using spring Mongo Template to persist data to MongoDb. I have a custom object which has a list.

```
Public Class CustomObject implements Serializable{
       private CustomType1 header; 
       private List<CustomType2> Values; 
}
```

I created a wrapper class in order to wrap my custom object and the wrapper class looks like this

```
public Class Wrapper { 
       private String id;
       private Object object; 
}
```

I am calling the save method like below

```
Wrapper wrapper = new wrapper(key, value); 
mongoTemplate.save(wrapper, collectionName);
```

**I am able to save the CustomObject to MongoDB but when I check the the document in the mongodb it is only showing the "header", the "values" field is getting ignored.** It is not giving any error.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: what is the code for CustomType2

Comment: Some Custom Class (POJO) which implements serializable which has some more subclasses as members

Comment: If I have all these custom classes in the classpath of the application where I am calling "mongoTemplate.save(wrapper, collectionName);", then i am able to see the list of custom objects as third field in the document inserted in mongoDB. But If I don't add these classes to the classpath, then I only see two fields in the document inserted, the List of custom objects field is missing.

Comment: Any Idea why this is happening? @JerylCook

Comment: your code is incomplete to answer..

Answer (score 0):

i think this is the flow you want..

```
@Document
Public Class CustomObject{
       private CustomType1 header; 
       private List<CustomType2> values;   
}

@Document
public Class Wrapper { 
       @Id
       private String key;
       private CustomObject value; 
}

...
...

CustomObject customObject = new CustomObject(header,values);

Wrapper wrapper = new Wrapper(key, customObject); 

mongoTemplate.save(wrapper)
```

;

Comment: I am looking to make this wrapper class generic so that we can reuse this for other objects as well. Also I don't want to add the CustomObject in the classpath of the Application where I am calling the save method.

Comment: try using this library for that http://mongojack.org  , mapping Java objects to MongoDB documents

Comment: I tried using MongoJack, My custom object has a calendar type and its giving "IllegalArgumentException: can't serialize class java.util.GregorianCalendar"

Comment: i don't see GregorianCalendar" in the code you posted.

Comment: "private List<CustomType2> values;" This CustomType2 object has a member variable of type GregorianCalendar.

Comment: Thanks @JerylCook, I am Working to get the solution using the mongoJack. In the process I came across a scenario to use Object Mapper to map the linkedHashMap to Object. I am getting the following exception in doing so "com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Expected type float, integer, or string." Can you help me with this. I am already using this mapper.registerModule(new ParameterNamesModule()).registerModule(new Jdk8Module()).registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
    mapper.findAndRegisterModules(); , but still giving the above exception