# How to set Nested Object with Mongotemplate Spring

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, mongotemplate

I'm still new in mongodb, If I have a class like below and I want to set a property Role which is Object Type Property, how can I achieve it ? please check the class below

```
@Document(collection="User")
public class UserBean {

    @Id
    private String id;

    private String userName;
    private String password;

    private RoleBean role;


}

@Document(collection="Role")
public class RoleBean {

    @Id
    private String id;

    private String roleID;
    private String roleName;


}
```

I need to set the UserBean's role property. So what is the best way to achieve it? Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

[Spring Mongo Template not saving the list of custom objects to MongoDb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51942478/spring-mongo-template-not-saving-the-list-of-custom-objects-to-mongodb) please see if this quation is already answered, or answer satisfies your requirements.